# facebook graph data not getting via curl

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to get graph api data for my website.  First I tried to get data as said in FB developer page using following link in browser(https://graph.facebook.com/?id= URL) it was giving me the right data but when I tried to get it via curl it is giving following error when I var_dump the data:

`array(1) { ["error"]=> array(4) { ["message"]=> string(38) "(#4) Application request limit reached" ["type"]=> string(14) "OAuthException" ["is_transient"]=> bool(true) ["code"]=> int(4) } }`

please help. is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you sent too many requests in too little time.

Solutions

1. Send less requests
2. Combine requests via the `/?ids={url1},{url2},{url3},...` endpoint

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#multirequests
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting#applimit

Comment: The request limits are calculated dynamically, and Facebook did not communicate static limits. So, there's no "true" answer for that

Comment: Also, have a look on the second link of my updated answer